# Suppose $(a_{n})$ is decreasing and $\lim a_{n}=0$, show that $0$ is a lower bound for $a_{n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $(a_{n})$ is decreasing and $\lim a_{n}=0$, show that $0$ is a lower bound for $a_{n}$.

From definition of convergence and $a_{n}$ being decreasing, we can see that any negative real number is a lower bound.

But how do i prove that $0$ is also a lower bound?

Comment: You may start by thinking what will happen if $0$ is not a lower bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to show that $0 \leq a_n$ for all $n$. Suppose not; since $(a_n)$ is decreasing, what can you say about $a_m$ for large $m$?

Comment: for large $m$, $a_{m} < 0$

Comment: exists a $m$ such that $a_{m} < 0$, then for $n\geq m$, $a_{n} < a_{m} < 0$, but by definition of convergence, for large $N$, the terms are in $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $0$. Let $\epsilon= -a_{m}$, then the contradiction is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that there is some $n_0$ such that $a_{n_0}<0$, say $a_{n_0} = -\epsilon < 0$.

As $a_n\rightarrow 0$, by definition of the limit, there exists an integer $N$ such that $\forall n\geq N,\, -\epsilon /2 < a_n < \epsilon /2$.
This implies that $n_0<N$. But we have $a_{n_0}<a_N$. These two facts put together contradicts the fact that $a_n$ is decreasing.

Comment: check your proof again

Answer (score 0):

Let $a:= \inf \{a_n: n \in \mathbb N\}$. If $ \epsilon >0$, then there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $a_N < a+ \epsilon$, hence, for $n>N$:

$$ a- \epsilon <a \le a_n < a+ \epsilon.$$

This gives:

$$|a_n-a|< \epsilon$$ for $n>N$.

Conclusion: $a_n \to a$. Consequence: $0=a=\inf \{a_n: n \in \mathbb N\}$.